# How to create prototypes with Axure RP 6.5 maintaining a 960 width for my content?

Tags: axure

I want to create the following 2 prototypes:

1. The content of the page is in a 960px width centralized. On screens like 1024, the left and right side has a single background color, say orange. The middle (with the 960 px width) has a white background color.
2. There is a screen wide blue banner at the top about 150px in height, but the content is still within a 960 width centralized again. Other than the screen wide blue banner everywhere else is simply a white background. A good example is the ux.stackexchange website itself.

I tried using axure create global guides > 960 16 column. But I ended up with a webpage that has all the contents consistently starting from 0px 0px aka from the left.

How do I create either prototype on Axure RP 6.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the alignment of the page and the background colour in the Page Style Editor. You can find it under: Wireframe > Page Style Editor...

[image: Page Style Editor]

The arrow marks the setting to align the page of the prototype in the middle of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the page settings (below the content area) to centre content and set the background colour, which will address both problems. Content will be centred when you generate the prototype. For 2, I recommend using a background master for the banner.